# xpath matching not working for queryparameters

Tags: xpath, wiremock

I am trying to put an AND condition in xpath match on query parameters, however it's not working.

I am creating multiple stubs, wherein uniqueId could contain likewise digits 00000 or 11111 but serviceName will be different. e.g.In first request, uniqueId is 1000001 and serviceName='ABC', in Second request, uniqueId is again 1000001 and serviceName is 'XYZ'. For both response will be different. I have created three stubs one for service ABC, 2nd for service XYZ and third is default without and xpath match.
When I call service with queryparameter contains uniqueId 1000001 and serviceName ABC or XYZ, everytime I get response of default stub.
Passing xml in query parameter

```
"queryParameters":{
      "xmlreqdoc": {
        "matchesXPath" : "//*[[local-name()='uniqueId'][text()[contains(.,'00000')]] AND //*[local-name()='serviceName'][text() = 'ABCDEFGH']]"
      }
    }
```

I have created stubs with priority given.. and seems like everytime default one gets returned. Following is the request xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service>
<serviceHeader>
<userId>XXXX</userId>
<password>XXXXX</password>
<serviceName>ABCDEFGH</serviceName>
</serviceHeader>
<serviceBody>
<subServiceName>add</subServiceName>
<uniqueId>00000</uniqueId>
</serviceBody>
</service>
```

Below is the stub mapping I have created

```
{
  "priority" : 1,
  "request": {
    "urlPath": "/testMappings",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": {
        "equalTo": "application/xml"
      },
      "Accept": {
        "equalTo": "application/xml"
      }
    },
    "queryParameters":{
      "xmlreqdoc": {
        "matchesXPath" : "//*[//[local-name()='uniqueId'][text()[contains(.,'00000')]] AND //*[local-name()='serviceName'][text() = 'ABCDEFGH']]"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 400,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type" : "application/xml"
    },
    "fixedDelayMilliseconds": 500,
    "bodyFileName": "ERROR.xml"
  }
}
```

Any help or pointers will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You've told us the incorrect syntax that you've tried, but you haven't told us what you're trying to achieve, so we can tell you what you did wrong, but we can't tell you how to make it right.

```
"//*[//[local-name()='uniqueId'][text()[contains(.,'00000')]] AND //*[local-name()='serviceName'][text() = 'ABCDEFGH']]"
```

Things that are obviously wrong here:

- `//` followed immediately by a predicate
- Unnecessary matching on local-name() when there are no namespaces involved
- Unnecessary use of `text()`
- Unnecessary use of contains() when you could use `=`
- `AND` should be `and`

Perhaps you want `//uniqueId = '00000' and //serviceName = 'ABCDEFGH'`

Comment: Michael, I’ll try pointers shared by you. In the meanwhile I need contains() here, As i want pattern matching e.g. uniqueId could have values like 230000012, 2132222245(combination of 2’s). I can have different service names in the different requests hence I need to match uniqueId and serviceName. Different services could have likewise uniqueId.

Comment: I suggest you try and update your question with a complete description of the requirement, and a more complete example, rather than drip-feeding information like this.

Comment: I have added  more description in the ask, possibly because of bad syntax I am not getting desired results.. Accidentally pasted one of code section that had compile errors. However wiremock standalone gets started but when I request for data then I am not getting expected results

Comment: I am seeing warning in wiremock console Warning: failed to evaluate the XPath expression //uniqueId = '00000' and //serviceName = 'ABCDEFGH'

Comment: That expression returns a boolean. Perhaps the software expects an XPath expression that returns a node-set. You haven't explained what you want your XPath expression to return.

Comment: //uniqueId[contains(text(),'00000')] and //serviceName[text()='ABCDEFGH']

This works fine when I am testing on online tools, however its not working with wiremock. 
This works fine in wiremock as long as I have only one mapping for that URL in the mappings set e.g. only uniqueId or serviceName. As soon as I have both in xpath than I am seeing warning "failed to evaluate the XPath expression" in wiremock console.

Comment: //*[uniqueId[contains(text(),'00000')] and //serviceName='ABCDEFGH'] worked for me. Thank you Michael!!

Comment: Sounds like you've found a bug in the XPath processor if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
//*[uniqueId[contains(text(),'00000')] and //serviceName='ABCDEFGH']
```

worked for me.